# Get debug status out of Flask Script Manager

Tags: python, flask, flask-script

I'm using Flask-Script and I've got a `manage.py` that looks like this.

```
from mypackage import create_app
from flask.ext.script import Manager

app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

I'll start my app with `python manage.py runserver --debug`

From within `manage.py`, how can I find out that runserver was called with `--debug`?

I've tried `app.debug` but that returns `False` and `manager.get_options()` returns an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've provided is fine-- here's a `mypackage.py` file to demonstrate that:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, current_app

test = Blueprint('user', __name__, url_prefix='/')

@test.route('/')
def home():
    return str(current_app.debug)

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(test)
    return app
```

Adding `--debug` reflects accurately (`True`) when you access the index page.